# Difference in declaring variable as a array index and "0"?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, methods, scope

I'm new to c# so be ready for some dumb questions.

My current task is to find a score from an array where the highest/lowest scores have been taken away, and if the highest/lowest occur more than once (ONLY if they occur more than once), one of them can be added:

eg. int[] scores = [4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5] therefore the final addition will be 4+8+6+5 = 23.

Another condition of the task is that LINQ cannot be used, as well as any of the System.Array methods. (you can see by my previously ask questions that has been a bit of a pain for me, since I solved this with LINQ in less than 5 minutes).

So here is the problem: I have working code the solves the problem but the task requires multiple methods/functions, so I cannot receive full marks if I have only 3 methods (including main). I have been trying to restructure the program but with all sorts of issues. Here is my code (just so I can explain it better):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring {
class Program {

    static int highOccurrence = 0;
    static int lowOccurrence = 0;
    //static int high; <------
    //static int low; <------

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] scores = { 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5 };

        findScore(scores);
        ExitProgram();
    }

    static int findOccurrence(int[] scores, int low, int high) { //find the number of times a high/low occurs

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++) {
            if (low == scores[i]) {
                lowOccurrence++;
                //record number of time slow occurs
            }

            if (high == scores[i]) {
                highOccurrence++;
                //record number of times high occurs                }
        }
        return highOccurrence;
    }

    static int findScore(int[] scores) { //calculates score, needs to be restructured

        int[] arrofNormal = new int[scores.Length];

        //int low = scores[0]; <----This is where the issue is
        //int high = scores[0]; <----- ^^^^^
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++) {             
            if (low > scores[i]) {
                low = scores[i];
            } //record lowest value

            if (high < scores[i]) {
                high = scores[i];
                //record highest value
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < scores.Length; x++) {
            if (scores[x] != low && scores[x] != high) {
                arrofNormal[x] = scores[x];
                //provides the total of the scores (not including the high and the low) 
            }
            total += arrofNormal[x];
        }

        findOccurrence(scores, low, high);
        if (highOccurrence > 1) { //if there is more than 1 high (or 1 low) it is added once into the total
            total += high;
            if (lowOccurrence > 1) {
                total += low;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + total);
        return total; //remove not all code paths return.. error
    }        
    static void ExitProgram() {
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit program: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end ExitProgram
}
}
```

I have placed arrows in the code above to show where my issue is. If I try to declare "high" and "low" as global variables, my final answer is always a few numbers off, buy if I leave the variables declared as "high = scores[0]" etc, I will get the right answer.

What I want ideally is to have separate methods for each step of the calculation, so right now I have method for finding the number of times a specific value shows up in the array. The next I would like to do is finding the highest/lowest value in the array, one method would do the final calculation, and the final one would write the results into the console window. The last two parts (finding the high/low and final calculation) are currently in the find score method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does high and low get their initial values when they're in the global scope.

Comment: For questions about improving working code consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com. For refactoring code to use methods - use VS refactoring to create method or get ReSharper plugin (if you have non-Express edition of Visual Studio).